# pagination for dynamic table using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, pagination

I created a FORM that collects the input data from the user and stores the data and gets the data shown in the table.

What I need is that I need PAGINATION for that table.

This is my code.

```js
// ------------- form submit ----------------

const name = document.getElementById("Name");
const email = document.getElementById("Email");
const mobileNumber = document.getElementById("mobilenumber");
const address = document.getElementById("Address");
const dbd = document.getElementById("Dateofbirth");
const nameerror = document.getElementById("NameValidationError");
const emailerror = document.getElementById("EmailValidationError");
const numbererror = document.getElementById("mobilenumberValidationError");
const addresserror = document.getElementById("AddressValidationError");
const dbderror = document.getElementById("DateofbirthValidationError");



var selectedRow = null

function onFormSubmit() {
    if (validate()) {
        var formData = readFormData();
        if (selectedRow == null)
            insertNewRecord(formData);
        else
            updateRecord(formData);
        resetForm();
    }
}

function readFormData() {
    var formData = {};
    formData["Name"] = name.value;
    formData["Email"] = email.value;
    formData["mobilenumber"] = mobileNumber.value;
    formData["Address"] = address.value;
    formData["Dateofbirth"] = dbd.value;
    return formData;
}

function insertNewRecord(data) {

    var table = document.getElementById("dataList").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = data.Name;
    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = data.Email;
    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = data.mobilenumber;
    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    cell4.innerHTML = data.Address;
    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(4);
    cell4.innerHTML = data.Dateofbirth;
    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(5);
    cell4.innerHTML = `<a onClick="onEdit(this)">Edit</a>
                       <a onClick="onDelete(this)">Delete</a>`;

  
}


function resetForm() {
    name.value = "";
    email.value = "";
    mobileNumber.value = "";
    address.value = "";
    dbd.value = "";
    selectedRow = null;
}
// ------------- form submit end----------------


// ------------- form edit----------------
function onEdit(td) {
    selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;
    name.value = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    email.value = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    mobileNumber.value = selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML;
    address.value = selectedRow.cells[3].innerHTML;
    dbd.value = selectedRow.cells[4].innerHTML;
}
// ------------- form edit end----------------


// ------------- form update----------------
function updateRecord(formData) {
    selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML = formData.Name;
    selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML = formData.Email;
    selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML = formData.mobilenumber;
    selectedRow.cells[3].innerHTML = formData.Address;
    selectedRow.cells[4].innerHTML = formData.Dateofbirth;
}
// ------------- form update end----------------


// ------------- form delete----------------
function onDelete(td) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {
        row = td.parentElement.parentElement;
        document.getElementById("dataList").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
        // resetForm();
    }
}
// ------------- form delete end----------------


// ------------- form validation----------------

function validate() {
  isValid = true;
    if (name.value == "") {
        isValid = false;
        nameerror.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!nameerror.classList.contains("hide"))
            nameerror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (email.value == ""){
        isValid = false;
        emailerror.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!emailerror.classList.contains("hide"))
            emailerror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (mobileNumber.value == ""){
        isValid = false;
        numbererror.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!numbererror.classList.contains("hide"))
            numbererror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (address.value == "") {
        isValid = false;
        addresserror.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!addresserror.classList.contains("hide"))
            addresserror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (dbd.value == "") {
        isValid = false;
        dbderror.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!dbderror.classList.contains("hide"))
            dbderror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    return isValid;
}
// ------------- form validation end----------------
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

body{
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
}
.main-heading{
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.list {
    width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=number],
input[type=Address],
input[type=date]
 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(185, 185, 185);
}
input[type=submit]:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(185, 185, 185);
}

form div.form-action-buttons {
    text-align: right;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #2c00ee;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover{
    color: red;
}

label.validation-error {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Registration
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/simple.css">
</head>

<body>



  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <!------------ form --------------->
       <h1 class="main-heading">Form</h1>
        <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();onFormSubmit();">
          <div>
            <label>Name</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="NameValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email Id</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="EmailValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Mobile Number</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="mobilenumberValidationError">This field is
              required </label>
            <input type="number" name="mobilenumber" id="mobilenumber">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Address</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="AddressValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="address" name="Address" id="Address">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Date of Birth</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="DateofbirthValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="date" name="Dateofbirth" id="Dateofbirth">
          </div>
          <div class="form-action-buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>

      </td>
    </tr>
<!------------ form end--------------->

<!------------ data entries--------------->
<tr>
  <td>
 <table id="dataList" class="list">
  <h1 class="main-heading">Data Entries</h1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email Id</th>
      <th>Mobile Number</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Date of birth</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">

  </tbody>
<!-- <div class="a">
  <a id="previousPage">Previous
    Page</a> <a id="nextPage">Next Page</a>
  Page Number: <span id="paginationPage"></span>
</div> -->
 </table>
<!------------ data entries--------------->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


  <script src="./js/simple.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please.. I need this today.

Comment: _.chunk(array, [size=1]) https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15

Comment: @antokhio - I am sorry I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// ------------- form submit ----------------

const name = document.getElementById("Name");
const email = document.getElementById("Email");
const mobileNumber = document.getElementById("mobilenumber");
const address = document.getElementById("Address");
const dbd = document.getElementById("Dateofbirth");
const nameerror = document.getElementById("NameValidationError");
const emailerror = document.getElementById("EmailValidationError");
const numbererror = document.getElementById("mobilenumberValidationError");
const addresserror = document.getElementById("AddressValidationError");
const dbderror = document.getElementById("DateofbirthValidationError");



var selectedRow = null

function onFormSubmit() {
    if (validate()) {
        var formData = readFormData();
        if (selectedRow == null)
            insertNewRecord(formData);
        else
            updateRecord(formData);
        resetForm();
    }
}

function readFormData() {
    var formData = {};
    formData["Name"] = name.value;
    formData["Email"] = email.value;
    formData["mobilenumber"] = mobileNumber.value;
    formData["Address"] = address.value;
    formData["Dateofbirth"] = dbd.value;
    return formData;
}

function insertNewRecord(data) {

    var table = document.getElementById("dataList").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
    cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = data.Name;
    cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = data.Email;
    cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = data.mobilenumber;
    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    cell4.innerHTML = data.Address;
    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(4);
    cell4.innerHTML = data.Dateofbirth;
    cell4 = newRow.insertCell(5);
    cell4.innerHTML = `<a onClick="onEdit(this)">Edit</a>
                       <a onClick="onDelete(this)">Delete</a>`;

  
}


function resetForm() {
    name.value = "";
    email.value = "";
    mobileNumber.value = "";
    address.value = "";
    dbd.value = "";
    selectedRow = null;
}
// ------------- form submit end----------------


// ------------- form edit----------------
function onEdit(td) {
    selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;
    name.value = selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    email.value = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    mobileNumber.value = selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML;
    address.value = selectedRow.cells[3].innerHTML;
    dbd.value = selectedRow.cells[4].innerHTML;
}
// ------------- form edit end----------------


// ------------- form update----------------
function updateRecord(formData) {
    selectedRow.cells[0].innerHTML = formData.Name;
    selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML = formData.Email;
    selectedRow.cells[2].innerHTML = formData.mobilenumber;
    selectedRow.cells[3].innerHTML = formData.Address;
    selectedRow.cells[4].innerHTML = formData.Dateofbirth;
}
// ------------- form update end----------------


// ------------- form delete----------------
function onDelete(td) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {
        row = td.parentElement.parentElement;
        document.getElementById("dataList").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
        // resetForm();
    }
}
// ------------- form delete end----------------


// ------------- form validation----------------

function validate() {
  isValid = true;
    if (name.value == "") {
        isValid = false;
        nameerror.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!nameerror.classList.contains("hide"))
            nameerror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (email.value == ""){
        isValid = false;
        emailerror.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!emailerror.classList.contains("hide"))
            emailerror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (mobileNumber.value == ""){
        isValid = false;
        numbererror.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!numbererror.classList.contains("hide"))
            numbererror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (address.value == "") {
        isValid = false;
        addresserror.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!addresserror.classList.contains("hide"))
            addresserror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    if (dbd.value == "") {
        isValid = false;
        dbderror.classList.remove("hide");
    } else {
        isValid = true;
        if (!dbderror.classList.contains("hide"))
            dbderror.classList.add("hide");
    }
    return isValid;
}
// ------------- form validation end----------------
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

body{
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
}
.main-heading{
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.list {
    width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=number],
input[type=Address],
input[type=date]
 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(185, 185, 185);
}
input[type=submit]:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px rgb(185, 185, 185);
}

form div.form-action-buttons {
    text-align: right;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #2c00ee;
    margin-right: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover{
    color: red;
}

label.validation-error {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Registration
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/simple.css">
</head>

<body>



  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <!------------ form --------------->
       <h1 class="main-heading">Form</h1>
        <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();onFormSubmit();">
          <div>
            <label>Name</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="NameValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email Id</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="EmailValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Mobile Number</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="mobilenumberValidationError">This field is
              required </label>
            <input type="number" name="mobilenumber" id="mobilenumber">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Address</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="AddressValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="address" name="Address" id="Address">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Date of Birth</label><label class="validation-error hide" id="DateofbirthValidationError">This field is
              required.</label>
            <input type="date" name="Dateofbirth" id="Dateofbirth">
          </div>
          <div class="form-action-buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>

      </td>
    </tr>
<!------------ form end--------------->

<!------------ data entries--------------->
<tr>
  <td>
 <table id="dataList" class="list">
  <h1 class="main-heading">Data Entries</h1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email Id</th>
      <th>Mobile Number</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Date of birth</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">

  </tbody>
<!-- <div class="a">
  <a id="previousPage">Previous
    Page</a> <a id="nextPage">Next Page</a>
  Page Number: <span id="paginationPage"></span>
</div> -->
 </table>
<!------------ data entries--------------->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


  <script src="./js/simple.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck